# How to use AWS api gateway in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

im trying to implement the aws api gateway into android studio, but i cannot find the `MyApiClient` class. Im following the tutorial: [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-android.html)

And in my build.gradle file i have the following imports:

```
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.3.3'
```

Hope you guys can help!

Comment: the one you download from the console for your API Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not complete the previous steps. From your link, on the top of the page:

> In this section, we will outline the steps to use an Android SDK generated by API Gateway of an API. Before proceeding further, you must have already completed the steps in Generate SDKs of an API Using the API Gateway Console.

Generate the SDK of an API first

If you already did , are you sure you followed **step 6** correctly?